# Regextmatch + partial vlookup in google spreadsheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a table with three columns in google sheets:

- Column A (raw data): it containss different strings for which I need to extract the character "Y" + a match with a string in columns B.
  -Columns B: is an unordered list of codes that can occur multiple times as a substring in column A
- Column C displays the expected outcome.

---

Column A (raw data):
Row 1: X Y Apple
Row 2: Z Apple
Row 3: K
Row 4: L M Y Orange

Column B (codes to match, unordered):
Row 1: Apple
Row 2: Orange
Row 3: Mango
Row 4: Banana

Column C (expected outcome):
Row 1: Y Apple
Row 2: Apple
Row 3: (empty cell)
Row 4: Y Orange

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you need, but is it this in cell C1?

```
=arrayformula(trim(if(regexmatch(A1:A,"Y "),"Y ",)&if(countif(B:B,iferror(regexextract(A1:A,"\ (\w+)$")))>=1,iferror(regexextract(A1:A,"\ (\w+)$")),)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it solved my question. Thank you!